# How do I switch users?

Tags: lightdm, switch-user

How does one switch users in Unity? (i.e., in the GUI, *not* `sudo`.)

I really want to launch another X session using a different WM, without abandoning the current one.

Comment: If like us you switch between users a lot and don't want to type password every time, consider this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/811953/switching-between-two-opened-x-sessions-without-reauthenticating

Answer (score 5):

Simply click on Second Icon from right (Session Indicator) on Unity panel and Select "Switch User Account".

[image]

Comment: Now if only I had that button.

Comment: @Thanatos Follow this answer to reinstall it. [“Session Menu” and “Me Menu” are missing after upgrade](http://askubuntu.com/a/133493/37006)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the top right hand corner of the screen and click on your user name to trigger the drop-down menu of options, then click on Switch User.

That's how I do it on my laptop with 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install xfswitch-plugin
```

Or via Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

I saw that on [How can I switch users from within XFCE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79318/how-can-i-switch-users-from-within-xfce)

Answer (score 0):

Using Ctrl+Alt+F1 (or others F* works for me; Ubuntu 18.04 && gdm (default) as login manager).

Hypothesis: If I am not wrong, gdm will after login lunch new X11 (or wayland) server instance and put it on some unused terminal (ctrl+alt+F[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]). So you can leave your session (actually whole graphical server) on where it is (probably ctrl+alt+F2) without any touch (for example i3wm by default does not lock its session) and show login screen, which is always on first virtual terminal.